# Watermark on animated gif with php

Tags: php, imagemagick, gif, watermark, animated-gif

I need a function that adds a watermark to an animated gif. How I can do that with PHP and ImageMagick?

This is my code, but it doesn't work.

```
function IMagickWatermark($sf, $sfDest, $sfLogo, $sGravity='southeast'){
        //$sCmd = "composite -compose bumpmap -gravity $sGravity $sfLogo \"$sf\" $sfDest";
        $sCmd = "convert \"$sf\" -coalesce -gravity south -draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 \"$sfLogo\"' \"$sfDest\"";
        exec($sCmd);
        return 1;
    }
$sf = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/test/source.gif";
$sfDest = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/test/dest.gif";
$sfLogo = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/test/logowithtext.gif";
IMagickWatermark($sf, $sfDest, $sfLogo, $sGravity='SouthEast');
```

Comment: Please post some code. I think php's gd library is good for the job.

Comment: Us folks at StackOverflow would love to help you but we need to see what you've already accomplished and where exactly you're having trouble to help you better.

Comment: I edit my question and add my code, but it dont work.

Comment: @Janus Troelsen, that script: http://gifbox.ru/test/test.php - i do not know why it doesnt (: May be my hoster dont unstall ImageMagick? How i can to know it?

Comment: try executing it on the command line (CLI) from a shell on your host machine

Comment: also try checking the apache error logs

Comment: dpkg --list | grep imagemagick
ii  imagemagick                      8:6.6.0.4-3ubuntu1.1                       image manipulation programs
Library is installed...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
$animation = ani.gif; 

$watermark = logo.png; 

$watermarked_animation = "morph.gif"; 

$cmd = " $animation -coalesce -gravity South ". 
" -geometry +0+0 null: $watermark -layers composite -layers optimize "; 

exec("convert $cmd $watermarked_animation ");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
shell_exec('for i in sphere*.gif; do convert $i  -font Arial -pointsize 20 \
      -draw "gravity south \
             fill black  text 0,12 \'Copyright\' \
             fill white  text 1,11 \'Copyright\' " \
      wmark_$i; done');

shell_exec("convert   -delay 20   -loop 0   wmark_sphere*.gif   animatespheres.gif");
$f = fopen("animatespheres.gif", 'rb');
fpassthru($f);
fclose($f);
?>
```

if you need to debug, remove the fopen,fpassthru,fclose lines and add echo's for the shell_execs.

Comment: What kind of files:

sphere*.gif

wmark_sphere*.gif

animatespheres.gif

Where is source, destination, file with logo or text..?

Comment: ``sphere<whatever>.gif`` are your input files. ``wmark_sphere<whatever>.gif`` are generated temporary files. ``animatespheres.gif`` is your result. there is no file with logo or text, it is dynamically generated. if you want to watermark using an image, read this: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/

Comment: It dont work:
`<?
ini_set("display_errors","1");
ini_set("display_startup_errors","1");
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
$sf = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/test/d1cdcdf2cf6dba7a12511d6077783895.gif";

shell_exec("for i in $sf; do convert $i  -font Arial -pointsize 20 \
      -draw \"gravity south \
             fill black  text 0,12 'Copyright' \
             fill white  text 1,11 'Copyright' \" \
      wmark_$i; done");


shell_exec("convert   -delay 20   -loop 0   wmark_sphere*.gif   animatespheres.gif");

fpassthru("animatespheres.gif");

?>`

that code: http://gifbox.ru/test/index.php

Comment: try now, i edited it to fix the quotes. try to understand the code. $a in a string quoted with double quotes will not work in php cause it thinks it's a php variable, even when it's not. that's why i exchanged the quotes.

Comment: You wrote: try executing it on the command line (CLI) from a shell on your host machineconvert. I try to do that with command: "/var/www/gifbox.ru/test/d1cdcdf2cf6dba7a12511d6077783895.gif" -coalesce -gravity south -draw 'image over 0,0 0,0 "/var/www/gifbox.ru/test/gifboxru.gif"' "/var/www/gifbox.ru/test/_d1cdcdf2cf6dba7a12511d6077783895.gif"


and gif with watermark is created! Byt when i run php script - it doesnt created.

Comment: I try: Warning: fpassthru() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /var/www/gifbox.ru/test/index.php on line 24

Comment: you might have a permissions issue. try running ``chmod -R ugo+rwx .`` from the directory where the images and script are located (``test``)

Comment: i set permissions for file and folder to 777. When i run script with: `$f = fopen("animatespheres.gif", 'rb');` - iget an error (file animatespheres.gif - does not exixt), but then i run script with: $f = fopen("animatespheres.gif", 'w'); and file was created with size=0b. Then i run with: `$f = fopen("animatespheres.gif", 'rb');`, but filesize = 0b.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help! User Bonzo suggested a working solution. Once again, many, many thanks!