# Add watermark to animated gif with PHP ImageMagick library

Tags: php, imagemagick

This works fine for none animated images:

```
$image = new Imagick($file);

$format = strtolower($image->getImageFormat());

$watermark = new Imagick('watermark.png');
$watermark->scaleImage($image->getImageWidth(), $watermark->getImageHeight());

$image->addImage($watermark);

$image->resetIterator();
$combined = $image->appendImages(true);

$data = base64_encode($combined->getImageBlob());

echo '<img src="data:image/' . $format . ';base64,' . $data . '">';
```

How can I make this work for animated gifs?
It just puts every frame below each other and the watermark below that.

Answer (score 0):

See below URL i am very sure it is very help full to you:-

[Watermark on animated gif with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531514/watermark-on-animated-gif-with-php)

Try this

```
$animation = ani.gif; 

$watermark = logo.png; 

$watermarked_animation = "morph.gif"; 

$cmd = " $animation -coalesce -gravity South ". 
" -geometry +0+0 null: $watermark -layers composite -layers optimize "; 

exec("convert $cmd $watermarked_animation ");
```

See also

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#composite

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21730

Comment: see also http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#composite http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21730

Comment: How can I do it with the PHP API?