# Imagick php MERGE GIF + PNG

Tags: php, animation, merge, imagemagick

My problem is similar to a closed question:
[Watermark on animated gif with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531514/watermark-on-animated-gif-with-php)

But how to use it? It's not like the PHP syntax. 
I try this:

```
<?php
$animation = 'images/gif/oleni.gif'; 
$watermark = 'gallery/258e5b33191223215aa05f55460aed2f.png'; 
$watermarked_animation = 'morph.gif'; 
$cmd = ' $animation -coalesce -gravity South '. 
' -geometry +0+0 null: $watermark -layers composite -layers optimize '; 
exec('convert $cmd $watermarked_animation '); 
?>
```

And nothing happened.
How to use this solution?

Comment: As expected. Does not work.

Comment: It seems that the case was quoted ... 
In the original there were doubles, I corrected them on the single. 
With single quotes to work, and works great with double...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't debug in the dark:

```
$command = 'convert ....';
exec($command, $output, $return_var);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- add these
var_dump($command);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($return_var);
```

will tell you exactly what output was produced from the program, and that output will generaly contain error messages.

Comment: It seems that the case was quoted ... 
In the original there were doubles, I corrected them on the single. 
With single quotes to work, and works great with double ...

Comment: What do you call a method? I would like to find documentation.