# Watermark to animated GIF with PHP ImageMagick library

Tags: php, image, animation, animated-gif, watermark

I have added PHP watermark animated image but i have faced problem the `orginal.gif` image is not animated after creating the watermark.

***Code:***

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage("orginal.gif");

$watermark = new Imagick();
$watermark->readImage("watermark.png");

// how big are the images?
$iWidth = $image->getImageWidth();
$iHeight = $image->getImageHeight();
$wWidth = $watermark->getImageWidth();
$wHeight = $watermark->getImageHeight();

if ($iHeight < $wHeight || $iWidth < $wWidth) {
    // resize the watermark
    $watermark->scaleImage($iWidth, $iHeight);

    // get new size
    $wWidth = $watermark->getImageWidth();
    $wHeight = $watermark->getImageHeight();
}

// calculate the position
$x = ($iWidth - $wWidth) / 2;
$y = ($iHeight - $wHeight) / 2;

$image->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $x, $y);

header("Content-Type: image/" . $image->getImageFormat());
echo $image;
?>
```

***orginal.gif***

[image]

***watermark.png***

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

**Description:** I have a form there is option to upload file, Upload file only accept gif image after upload the gif image the gif image will show with the logo watermark in the site. But when give watermark image the watermark GIF image is not animated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531514/watermark-on-animated-gif-with-php

Comment: @Alex i have checked above link but that is same... Failed to convert image...

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
//use imagemagick command-line
passthru("convert -coalesce orginal.gif -gravity SouthEast -draw 'Image Over 10,10,0,0    $watermark.png' Output.gif");
```